# Create Javascript object with one array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How to create a javascript object runtime like following

```
task{
 timestamp:string;
tasklist: array of object
}
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. Please provide valid examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an *object initialiser* for that:

```
var task = {
    timestamp: "this is a string",
    tasklist: []
};
```

`[]` creates an array (an empty one). JavaScript doesn't have "array(s) of object," a standard array can hold anything. (JavaScript does, these days, have typed arrays for other things, like 8-bit integers, but not objects.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var task = {
   timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
   tasklist: [new Object(), new Object()]

};
```

This could be one way to do it. Then you can get access to the property in this way:

```
task.tasklist[i...n]
```

You could also create an array like this:

```
var task = []
```

and then assign the timestamp as a property:

```
task.timestamp = //myTimestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var task = {};
task.timestamp = 'your string';
task.tasklist = [];
```

and then add task list objects like:

```
task.tasklist.push({'id': 5, 'name': 'task list 5'});
```

or:

```
var tasklistentry = {};
tasklistentry.id = 5;
tasklistentry.name = 'task list 5';
task.tasklist.push(tasklistentry);
```